# Cannot install SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2012 and got this message:

```
SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The resource 'Microsoft.SQL.Chainer.PackageData.Package.xml' failed to load
from 'E:\PCUSOURCE\x64\Microsoft.SQL.Chainer.PackageData.Package.dll'.

Error code 0x85650003.
```

What should I do?

Comment: What operating system installed in this machine? and is that has updated with latest build? before installing MSSQL 2012

Comment: Yes it's updated and Windows Server 2012 Standard. Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with resolving this?  Having the exact same error here.  In this case I am setting up a Windows 7 Pro dev machine w/ SQL 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2012.  Based on other threads I am thinking maybe the VS install kicked off some SQL 2012 components and that is causing issues.

Comment: @pseudocoder I think I gave up on installing it or didn't solve the issue in some other way. Feel free to post if you figure out a workaround or a solution.